# php date conversion mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, jquery-ui, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Managing date formats differences between PHP and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415092/managing-date-formats-differences-between-php-and-mysql)

I am using jQuery ui datepicker

and initialized with following format

```
$("#task_date").datepicker({dateFormat : "m/d/y",
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "<?= base_url(); ?>assets/img/calendar.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true
        });
```

so the date format is in `"m/d/y"` ,how can i convert it to mysql date format ?

also i need to convert from mysql date format to `"m/d/y"` ...

Answer (score 2):

Change `dateFormat : "m/d/y"` to

```
dateFormat : "yy-mm-dd"    //Which is same as PHP's 'Y-m-d' or '2012-07-14'
```

And, for converting to `m/d/y` format(in jQuery), you'll need to do:

```
var date = $('#task_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
```

Date conversion(in [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) and in [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php))

Comment: this would save so much coding, +1

Comment: pardon me , but its requirement ..