# MM-YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss on php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

If i have a string with format "MM-YYYY" like `04-2016`,
how to get them into datetime format mysql which is "YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss".

I wonder like this : 2016-04-01 00:00:00,
I am using php with mysql.

Comment: post your code in question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing datetime as UTC in PHP/MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349280/storing-datetime-as-utc-in-php-mysql)

Comment: `$string = '04-2016';
$dto = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', '01-' . $string . ' 00:00:00');
echo $dto->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Managing date formats differences between PHP and MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415092/managing-date-formats-differences-between-php-and-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

```
$d = '04-2016';

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', ('01-'.$d));
$date->setTime(0, 0, 0);

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // Outputs 2016-04-01 00:00:00
```

Something like the above will allow you to get the format you want in PHP, then you just have to insert it into your database as you currently are.

Comment: Thanks, the result is 2016-04-03 00:00:00, still wrong

Comment: @FadlyDzil Yeah sorry about that, I accidentally used `01` rather than `d`, should be working now.

Answer (score 0):

you have date time formate with Am and pm then use below code

```
 $d='03-03-2016 03:07:22';

echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s a',strtotime($d));
```